# Angular Show/Hide Button

Tags: angular, button

Hello please forgive me but I am new to angular
I am makeing an angular flight Schedular application I got everything to work so far however I cant see to get the flightlist component (parent component) to "communicate" with the show-hide-component (child component). I know that I ccorrectly coded all the properties and methods for the button for the show-hide-component (child component)

what is suppost to happen is the user clicks the "hide" button and the showhide child component hides the flightlist parent component and vice versa if the user clicks the "Show" button then the flighlist parent component will then reappear.

show-hide-component.component.ts (child component) Code:

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-hide-component',
  templateUrl: './show-hide-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-hide-component.component.css']
})
export class ShowHideComponentComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() isShowHide!: boolean; // button caller 
 textShowHide:string = "Hide";//button display text
 visible:boolean = true;
  @Output() isActivated = new EventEmitter<boolean>();​
  constructor() { }
    onShowHide(){
    this.isShowHide = true;   
    this.isActivated.emit( this.isShowHide );
    
    this.visible = this.visible?false:true;
    this.textShowHide= this.visible?"Hide":"Show"; 
    }  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

show-hide-component.component.html (child component) code

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onShowHide() ">
    {{textShowHide}}</button>
```

flightlist component ts file (parent component)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { __importDefault } from 'tslib';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flight-list',
  templateUrl: './flight-list.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class FlightListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input()
  flights!: any[];
  subtitle = 'Active Flight Schedule';
  show!: boolean;
  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges): void {
 this.show  =  this.isShowHide;
}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  //deleteFlight(){
    //to do
 //}
}
```

flightlist component html (parent component) * please note I took out table information to save on space let me know if you need it

```html
<br>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">{{subtitle}}<app-show-hide-component> </app-show-hide-component></h3>
<table class="table table-ho"*ngIf="true;false">
<!-- list of flights goes here -->
</table>
```

If someone can please help me figure out what I missed  I would much apprecate it.

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue and expected result!

Comment: You did not yet mention what is the current behavior of this thing? What is happening right now? Why is the current behavior not working out for you? Can you include the whole template of your `show-hide-component`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the output emitted. This is the angular doc for your reference
https://docs.angular.lat/guide/inputs-outputs

```
<app-show-hide-component (isActivated)="callYourFunction()"> </app-show-hide-component>
```

I am sharing a stackblitz example for reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dv8nwv